# groupgridview yii grouping column

Tags: php, yii

its my view code

```
 $this->widget('ext.groupgridview.GroupGridView', array(
          'id' => 'grid1',
          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          'extraRowColumns' => "hi",
          'extraRowExpression' => '"<b style=\"font-size: 3em; color: green\">ff</b>"',
          'columns'=>$columns,
        ));
```

it showing the following error

```
Alias "ext.groupgridview.GroupGridView" is invalid.
```

reference : http://groupgridview.demopage.ru/index.php?r=site/extrarow

Answer (score 0):

you must have a folder named groupgridview, containing GroupGridView.php file in your protecetd/extensions folder

download [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/groupgridview):

and unpack it in extensions

Answer (score 0):

add `'ext.groupgridview.*',` in import array in config/main.php